# References about distances between singular probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, wiener-measure

I would be interested in references on the topic of distances between probability measures that are singular with one another and not reduced to trivial ones. For example from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70689/total-variation-distance-and-mutually-singular-probability-measure) we know that total variation distance is not suitable for such a problem. In the end I am looking for a structure that would be fine enough to be able to address mutually singular Wiener measures in a non trivial way (for example it is well known that the Wiener measures associate with the two process driven by a BM are mutually singulars : $X^1_t =\sigma_1.W_t$ and $X^2_t =\sigma_2.W_t$, with $X^i_0=0, i=1,2$ as soon as $\sigma_1\not=\sigma_2$ so finding a meaningful distance between those measures is a matter of interest for me). 
Best regards

Edit following the advice of Ilya here i what I could set up using the Wasserstein representation of Kantorovitch distance.

So let's formalize the set up : 
Let $(X^1_t)_{t\geq 0},(X^2_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be two processes defined by as $X_0^i =1,X^i_t=e^{\mu.t + \sigma_i.W^i_t$}, i=1,2$ with respect to 2 Brownian motions $W^1_t$ and $W^2_t$. The relation between the 2 process $W^1_t, W^2_t$ is left unspecified and we do not impose that $(W^1_t, W^2_t)$ is a 2 dimensional BM at the moment.

Let's note $\mathcal{L}_i$ the marginal law's of $(X^i_t)_{t\geq 0},i=1,2$, $X^i$ seen as a random variables in $C_1(\mathbb{R^+},\mathbb{R^+})$ the space of continuous function s.t. $f(0)=1$, and $\forall t\geq 0, f(t)\geq 0$, the measures being over sets of the Borel sigma-field resulting from topology of the sup norm over compacts of this functional space.
Now the space $\mathcal{J}$ of all the joint laws over state space $C_1(\mathbb{R^+},\mathbb{R^+})^2$ with marginals equals to $\mathcal{L}_1$ and $\mathcal{L}_2$ We define the distance between those 2 measure (which are btw mutually singulars) as :
$$d_{KW}(\mathcal{L}_1,\mathcal{L}_2)=inf_{J\in \mathcal{J}}(\mathbb{E^J}[d(X^1,X^2)])$$

So now using Ilya's ideas and specifying the $d$ in the preceding infimum, as $d(x,y)=sup_{s\geq0}(|x(s)-y(s)|) $, using a particular $J_W\in \mathcal{J}$ which is the one where  $W^1_t= W^2_t$ I can rewrite using Burkholder, Davies, Gundy inequality (maybe that's too much) that :

$d_{KW}(\mathcal{L}_1,\mathcal{L}_2)\leq \mathbb{E^{J_W}}[|X^1_s-X^2_s|^*])$ 
(here the star is for the sup) 
$\mathbb{E^{J_W}}[|X^1_s-X^2_s|^*])\leq C_1\mathbb{E^{J_W}}[<X^1_.-X^2_.>_\infty^{1/2}])=F^{J_W}$

I have not finished the calculations yet but even though, I bet that thanks to the negative drift it should be possible for $F^{J_W}$ to be bounded and that this bound tends to $0$ as $\sigma_1 - \sigma_2\to 0$ ( I think this was Ilya's original idea). 
Anyway this would not prove that $d_{KW}(\mathcal{L}_1,\mathcal{L}_2)$ is not trivially equal to 0 for a better choice of $J \in\mathcal{J}$ this is why I'm still a bit unsatisfied with this example. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wassertstein/Kantorovich metric is quite natural to use in case TV is too conservative, you can also check out [this](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/metrics.pdf) classic reference on other distances.

For example, think of two processes with exponential decay, e.g. GBMs with very strong negative drift (same for both) and slightly different volatilities. The TV distance between them is going to be $1$, but Kantorovich metric can be bounded by their average distance assuming coupling over the same driving Brownian motion, which can be estimated using supermartingale inequalities. I would expect this distance to go to $0$ as volatilities converge.

Comment: This very interesting reference has been pointed out to me on Mathoverflow but I couldn't figure out an example where two mutually singular probability measures would have non trivial distance. You mentioned Wassertstein/Kantorovich distances as a candidates but do you have example to illustrate how those metric could be used in this context ? Best regards –

Comment: @TheBridge: edited, please tell me whether you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for the example more details on the calculations on the supermartingale bounds and the way the coupling works  (and information about the distance used in the Kantorovicth metric in your example), would be appreciated, but anyway, thank's for pointing me to the right direction ( which was under my nose but that I couldn't see) Best regards

Comment: I have edited my post to try to elaborate on your idea but there are still some points that are yet not so clear to me. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: why would this distance be 0?

Comment: The question would rather be IMO why not ? or "how to prove that it is not trivial?", because if it is, this is again a distance which is not sharp enough. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge: sorry, I've misread it. Of course it is not trivially $0$, as it is a metric, and that would imply that two distributions are the same - and they aren't

Comment: that's right, off course ! thank's